# Reference for Euler's Introductio in Analysin Infinitorum

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, euler

In the following [answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2788/was-riemanns-zeta-function-paper-based-on-eulers-unproven-observation#) it has been claimed that "The reference here is not to Euler's 1737 "factorization" of the harmonic series but to 1748 Introductio in Analysin Infinitorum, where the identity for $s>1$ appears." Can anyone please tell me on which page can I find the following fact? I  found a book by Euler, which is translated into English and it is titled as 'Introduction to  Analysis of the  Infinite ' Book 1. I found at page 235 of that book that Euler was aware of the fact that harmonic series, i.e. when $s=1$, is divergent. But I can't still find the case where $s>1$.

> Here is [Wilkins's translation of Riemann's paper](http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/ezeta.pdf). Remarks at the
>   start of [the paper](http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/ezeta.pdf) show that Riemann was well aware of the
>   convergence issues:"*For this investigation my point of departure is
>   provided by the observation of Euler that the product*
>   $\prod\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p^{s}}}=\sum\frac{1}{n^{s}}$ *if one
>   substitutes for $p$ all prime numbers, and for $n$ all whole numbers.
>   The function of the complex variable $s$ which is represented by these
>   two expressions, wherever they converge, I denote by $\zeta(s)$. Both
>   expressions converge only when the real part of $s$ is greater than
>   $1$; at the same time an expression for the function can easily be
>   found which always remains valid*". **The reference here is not to
>   Euler's 1737 "factorization" of the harmonic series but to 1748
>   Introductio in Analysin Infinitorum, where the identity for $s>1$
>   appears.** Although Euler did not work with convergence in the modern
>   sense he already knew the difference between $s=1$ and $s>1$ cases
>   since he summed the Basel series in 1735 ($s=2$, later all even $s$),
>   and used unlimited growth of [harmonic series to prove infinitude of
>   primes](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/HEDI-2006-03.pdf) in that 1737 paper.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the reference is to [Euler's *Introductio in Analysin Infinitorum (Introduction to Analysis of the Infinite)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introductio_in_analysin_infinitorum) in which Euler investigates infinite series. The reference seems to point to **Volume 1**, **Chapter XV**, which is titled "Concerning Series Arising From the Expansion of Factors."

The English translation by Ian Bruce of the *Introductio* is in the public domain, and I'm guessing that you have found that file. If not, the full file can be found on Ian Bruce's site, [17centurymaths.com](http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/introductiontoanalysisvol1.htm) (or just [click here for Chapter XV](http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/euler/introductiontoanalysisvolone/ch15vol1.pdf)). The identity is specifically found on **pages 470 and 471** of that translation, **§273**.

The identity is first explicity stated with $s = 1$ in §273. §274, however, is where he states the more generalised identity for case where $s \neq 1$ (referring to $s$ as $n$ instead), investigating this further in subsequent sections. Be warned, however, that Euler's notation, even post-translation, is very different from the modern standard (e.g. using simply $l$ sans parentheses to denote the natural logarithm function).

I hope this helps!

Comment: I also found the same thing. I know he dealt with the case $s>1$, $s \in \mathbb{N}$. But I am really curious to know whether he really dealt with the case $s>1$, $s \in \mathbb{R}, s \not \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: As far as I can tell, he only examined $s \in \mathbb{N}$ in the *Introductio* but I'm not familiar enough with his other works to know if he ventured into $s \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Euler only considered the zeta function at integral values of $s$. He did not work with it as a function of a real variable.